# Electron canvas image quality reduced

Tags: javascript, electron

I have attached a screenshot of two views of a Javascript app I am writing. The view is of an image rendered on the 2D canvas. The window on the left is Chrome (v. 66), while the window on the right is Electron (v. 2.0.2, running Chromium). The files I am using are exactly the same, with the exception of the Electron wrapper. The image quality is degraded in the Electron window. Why might that be? The resolution of the screen is 3440 x 1440.

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing

Answer (score 0):

Electron 2.0.2 is running Chrome v. 61. I switched to using nw.js which uses Chrome v. 66 and did not have this issue of reduced image quality/anti-aliasing.